# npm - 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork

Tags: npm, http-status-code-404, npm-registry

Running a period npm update I received this error:

> npm ERR! code E404
>
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork - Not found
>
> npm ERR! 404  'https-proxy-agent-snyk-fork@*' is not in the npm registry.
>
> npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
>
> npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'proxy-agent'

I already tried to change the registry path to both http://registry.npmjs.org/ and https://registry.npmjs.org/ with and without final "/" and to set strict-ssl to false, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Once I got similar error, and what worked for me was this (I hope also to you):

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
npm -g install npm
npm cache clean -f
```

and try again to run period npm update as you did before.